# numpy ndarray indexing with __index__ method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, magic-methods

I don't understand how indexing of a numpy ndarray works, when using a custom class instance as the index.

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __index__(self):
        return 1,2

foo = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
bar = MyClass()

print(foo[1,2])
print(foo[bar])
```

I expect to get the same result (6) from both print functions. But from the second one, where the class instance is used a the index, I receive an error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

If I call the __index__ method explicitly with

```
print(foo[bar.__index__()])
```

it works. But this defeats the purpose of the magic method.

If I call the array with just one index, everything works fine:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __index__(self):
        return 1

foo = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
bar = MyClass()

print(foo[1])
print(foo[bar])

>>> [4 5 6]
>>> [4 5 6]
```

---

So what I don't get:

- The ndarray can use the output of the __index__ method for multiple dimensions. Seen when calling it explicitly.
- The ndarray does coll the __index__ method. Seen in the second example.
- But for some reason, this does not work at the same time. Why?

Did I miss something, or does the ndarray not support this kind of indexing?

---

I just want to add, that it apparently doesn't matter, how the __index__ method outputs its result. I tried:

```
return a, b
return (a, b)
return tuple((a, b))
```

None of them worked for me.

Comment: Implementing `__index__` means "my object represents an integer, and the return value of `__index__` is the integer it represents". It doesn't mean whatever you seem to think it means.

Comment: Yeah ok, so in my case my object represents a coordinate in 2D space, very similar to a normal Vector. I now wanted to use this object to get a specific element of an ndarray.I thought that the this is the right way. But can this only be used for single integers, not for multiple ones?

Comment: @Nereos, did you manage to solve the issue of converting your custom object to something that numpy can use in indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__), `__index__` method `Must return an integer.`

That's why your attempt didn't work, while the "one index" example worked.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know, that `__index__` must return an integer to work at all. Because a ndarray can handle multiple indexes, and the method can be called explicitly, I hoped these two could be combined. Would be very handy in my opinion. But ok.